# Перемещение курсора мыши по диагонали

Tags: java, графика, ui

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть две точки экрана с целочисленными координатами, мне нужно построить диагональ между ними и по целочисленным координатам этой диагонали плавно перемещать курсор мыши с помощью Robot.

Если использовать double значения, то все более менее понятно, вычисляем длину диагонали, определяем шаг и передвигаем. Но так как точки на экране целые, то тут уже вроде не так всё просто.

Может есть какие-нибудь специальные библиотеки, или уже готовые решения?

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел готовое решение:

```
package robot;

import java.awt.*;

public class MainClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        mouseGlide(50, 50, 400, 600, 10, 1000);
    }

    private static void mouseGlide(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, int t, int n) {
        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();
            double dx = (x2 - x1) / ((double) n);
            double dy = (y2 - y1) / ((double) n);
            double dt = t / ((double) n);
            for (int step = 1; step <= n; step++) {
                Thread.sleep((int) dt);
                r.mouseMove((int) (x1 + dx * step), (int) (y1 + dy * step));
            }
        } catch (AWTException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот [источник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387483/how-to-move-a-mouse-smoothly-throughout-the-screen-by-using-java#9387800). Правда код нуждается в доработке.